# routeProvider only half working

Tags: angularjs, url-routing, ngroute

I have the following code in my `app.js`.

```
var app = angular.module("TacoTime", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) { 
$routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
        controller  : 'HomeController'
    })

    // route for the directions page
    .when('/list', {
        templateUrl : 'views/list.html',
        controller  : 'ListController'
    })
    .otherwise({ 
      redirectTo: '/' 
    }); 
}]);
```

When I have the plain `/` I go to `home.html`. When I try `/lists` I get an error saying Nothing matches the given URI.

I've been tearing my hair out wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using html5mode?  If not, make sure you're using the url '#/' and '#/list'

Comment: to add more to my initial comment, your route is `/list` and you are saying when you try `/lists` you get an error...

Comment: Ronnie - /list. Was a typo, sorry.
I don't think I'm using html5mode

Comment: Nicholas - when I typed in /#/list in the browser, it worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try '/views/list.html' in the templateUrl